# Ruby core extensions with modules

Tags: ruby

Basically I have two modules: `CoreExtensions::CamelcasedJsonString` and `…::CamelcasedJsonSymbol`. The latter one overrides the `Symbol#to_s`, so that the method returns a `String` which is extended with the first module. I don't want every string to be a `CamelcasedJsonString`. This is the reason why I try to apply the extension instance specific.

My problem is, that `Symbol#to_s` seems to be overridden again after I included my module (the last spec fails):

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
require 'spec'

module CoreExtensions

  module CamelcasedJsonString; end

  module CamelcasedJsonSymbol

    alias to_s_before_core_extension to_s
    def to_s(*args)
      to_s_before_core_extension(*args).extend(CamelcasedJsonString)
    end

  end
  ::Symbol.send :include, CamelcasedJsonSymbol

end

describe Symbol do

  subject { :chunky_bacon }

  it "should be a CamelcasedJsonSymbol" do
    subject.should be_a(CoreExtensions::CamelcasedJsonSymbol)
  end

  it "should respond to #to_s_before_core_extension" do
    subject.should respond_to(:to_s_before_core_extension)
  end

  specify "#to_s should return a CamelcasedJsonString" do
    subject.to_s.should be_a(CoreExtensions::CamelcasedJsonString)
  end

end
```

However the following example works:

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
require 'spec'

module CoreExtensions
  module CamelcasedJsonString; end
end

class Symbol
  alias to_s_before_core_extension to_s
  def to_s(*args)
    to_s_before_core_extension(*args).extend(CoreExtensions::CamelcasedJsonString)
  end
end

describe Symbol do

  subject { :chunky_bacon }

  it "should respond to #to_s_before_core_extension" do
    subject.should respond_to(:to_s_before_core_extension)
  end

  specify "#to_s should return a CamelcasedJsonString" do
    subject.to_s.should be_a(CoreExtensions::CamelcasedJsonString)
  end

end
```

---

*Update: Jan 24, 2010*

The background of my problem is that I try to convert a huge nested hash
structure into a JSON string. Each key in this hash is a Ruby `Symbol` in the
typical underscore notation. The JavaScript library which consumes the JSON
data expects the keys to be strings in camelcase notation. I thought that
overriding the `Symbol#to_json` method might be the easiest way. But that
didn't work out since `Hash#to_json` calls first `#to_s` and afterwards
`#to_json` on each key. Therefore I thought it might be a solution to extend
all Strings returnd by `Symbol#to_s` with a module which overrides the
`#to_json` method of this specific string instance to return a string that has
a `#to_json` method which returns itself in camelcase notation.

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to monkey patch `Hash#to_json`.

If someone wants to take a look into the JSON implementation I'm using, here is the link: http://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/lib/json/pure/generator.rb (lines 239 and following are of interest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second monkeypatch works since you are re-opening the Symbol class.

The first one doesn't because all the include does is add the module in the list of included modules. These get called only if the class itself doesn't define a specific method, or if that method calls super. So your code never gets called.

If you want to use a module, you must use the `included` callback:

```
  module CamelcasedJsonSymbol
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        alias_method_chain :to_s, :camelcase_json
      end
    end

    def to_s_with_camelcase_json(*args)
      to_s_without_camelcase_json(*args).extend(CamelcasedJsonString)
    end
  end
```

I've used active_record `alias_method_chain`, which you should always do when monkey patching. It encourages you to use the right names and thus avoid collisions, among other things.

That was the technical answer.

On a more pragmatic approach, you should rethink this. Repeatedly extending strings like this is not nice, will be a huge performance drain on most implementations (it clears the whole method cache on MRI, for instance) and is a big code smell.

I don't know enough about the problem to be sure, or suggest other solutions (maybe a Delegate class could be the right thing to return?) but I have a feeling this is not the right way to arrive to your goals.

---

Since you want to convert the keys of a hash, you could pass an option to `#to_json` and monkeypatch that instead of `#to_s`, like:

```
{ :chunky_bacon => "good" }.to_json(:camelize => true)
```

My first idea was to monkeypatch `Symbol#to_json` but that won't work as you point out because Hash will force the keys to strings before calling to_json, because javascript keys must be strings. So you can monkeypatch Hash instead:

```
module CamelizeKeys
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      alias_method_chain :to_json, :camelize_option
    end
  end

  def to_json_with_camelize_option(*args)
    if args.empty? || !args.first[:camelize]
      to_json_without_camelize_option(*args)
    else
      pairs = map do |key, value|
        "#{key.to_s.camelize.to_json(*args)}: #{value.to_json(*args)}"
      end
      "{" << pairs.join(",\n") << "}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've a huge nested hash structure. Each key is a ruby symbol in underscore notation. I try to convert each symbol into a string in camelcase notation, because the javascript library which consumes the JSON data expects keys in this notation. I thought my approach might be faster than traversing the whole hash.

Example: { :chunky_bacon => "some value" }.to_json should be something like '{"chunkyBacon":"some value"}'

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Don't hesitate to modify your question accordingly. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far. I updated my question. The problem is that Hash#to_json does not call sth. like Symbol#to_json but Symbol#to_s#to_json instead. I really don't now if there is an easy way to monkey patch Hash#to_json.

Comment: Ah, right. So indeed monkeypatching Hash#to_json is your best bet then. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That looks kind of complicated.  I probably don't understand what it is you're trying to achieve, but what about something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

class Symbol

  alias_method :old_to_s, :to_s
  def to_s(*args)
    if args == [:upcase]
      old_to_s.upcase
    else
      old_to_s(*args)
    end
  end

end

puts :foo                   # => foo
puts :foo.to_s(:upcase)     # => FOO
```

and a partial spec:

```
describe :Symbol do

  it "should return the symbol as a string when to_s is called" do
    :foo.to_s.should eql 'foo'
  end

  it "should delegate to the original Symbol.to_s method when to_s is called with unknown arguments" do
    # Yeah, wish I knew how to test that
  end

  it "should return the symbol name as uppercase when to_s(:upcase) is called" do
    :foo.to_s(:upcase).should eql "FOO"
  end

end
```